# Universal install buildout failed. Permission denied.

Tags: plone

A fresh plone install is failing with this error:

```
Copying buildout skeleton
Fixing up bin/buildout
Building Zope/Plone; this takes a while...
Buildout returned an error code: 126; Aborting.
Buildout failed. Unable to continue

Installation has failed.
See the detailed installation log at /home/adrigen/Downloads/Plone-4.3.2-UnifiedInstaller/install.log
```

The log says

```
/bin/sh: 1: /home/adrigen/Develop/Plone-4.3.2/zinstance/bin/buildout: Permission denied
```

The folder permissions say

```
drwxr-sr-x 7 plone_buildout plone_group 4096 Nov 21 19:01 Plone-4.3.2
```

This is when I run the install with and without a sudo prefix. What might the issue be here?

Comment: And on the bin/buildout file, what parmissions do you have ?

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 adrigen adrigen 359 Nov 21 19:39 buildout
I assume I should change this to the same as the plone directory. Is that correct? I wonder why this happened this time.

Comment: Should I run buildout to finish the install?

Comment: I made it executable and ran the buildout and it worked. I am still not sure why this intervention was required during UniversalInstall

Comment: maybe a bug during the installation

Comment: @Adripants: I'd expect it to be `-rwxr-xr-x` instead.